# How to use content place holders with dynamic master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written a content system which allows a user to edit pages for a website. When they edit a page they can select a template to use for the page.  All of the content and selections are in a database.

When I display a page, I call just one file (DisplayPage.aspx), passing the page ID.  This uses the page ID to select the chosen template, to display the page.

Each template has it's own set of content placeholders, some are common amongst all the templates and some are unique for that template.  My question is, how can I reference and populate all of the content placeholders for a template, given that the master page is chosen dynamically and the amount / names of the placeholders will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all Controls and recursively through their subcontrols and check the type and if they are contentplaceholders you have the ID.

```
for (string cphID in ((MasterPageType)this.MasterPage).ContentPlaceHolders)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(cphID);
}
```

Comment: I can't get that to work at all, though I understand what you're saying.